# SQL Index on a portion of the column

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a large SQL Server table with many columns. I have tried to optimize the table for minimum storage space as queries are not done often.

However recently I have been given a requirement to query this table looking for a specific GUID.

Due to space constraints I do not want to put a index on the GUID as this will use many GBs of storage.

Is there a way that I can add a index on the column, but only on the first 2 characters?

This should be enough to reduce the data set to a small enough amount, to then go and do a physical read? Resulting in a hybrid between speed and storage space.

In short, if I have a `varchar(36)` column called `ID`, can I add an index only on the first two character of that column?

```
create index(2) on ID
```

Comment: Create a (computed) column which only contains the part you want and build index on that?

Comment: Index on 2 characters of guid is very inefficient. It will be space waste. Think about the ingex on real guid and maybe you can save some space by compression of your table

Comment: If you care about storage considerations why are you storing GUIDS as `varchar(36)`? The correct datatype is `uniqueidentifier` - 16 bytes not 38.

Comment: from comments below, it seems the best would just be to make the column `uniqueidentifier' and then just make a normal index on that.

Answer (score 2):

> If I have a varchar(36) column called ID can I add an index only on the first two character of that column.

yes you can..this type of index is called computed index...

Below is some test data to demonstrate how to create a computed column and index on it

```
create table t12
(
id varchar(36)  default CONVERT(varchar(36), NEWID())
)


insert into t12
default values
go 100

--add computed column
alter table t12
add col2 as left(id,2)

--create index
create index nci on t12(col2)

select col2 from t12 where col2='30'-this does a index seek
```

To create an index on computed column,it has satisfy some properties which are explained [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1702/how-to-create-indexes-on-computed-columns-in-sql-server/) and you can check whether your column satisfies those properties

```
SELECT    
     COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('DBO.t12'), 'col2','IsComputed') AS IsComputed,
     COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('DBO.t12'), 'col2','IsDeterministic') AS IsDeterministic,
     COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('DBO.t12'), 'col2','IsPrecise') AS IsPrecise,
     COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('DBO.t12'), 'col2','IsIndexable') AS IsIndexable
```

if `IsPRecise` [property is not satisfied](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-indexes-on-sql-server-computed-columns/), you may have to  persist the column ,which may then take space

**Note:**
creating an computed index on large column may need huge memory to sort(use :sort in tempdb option) and you may run out of memory.I tried to create a computed index on 26 billion rows of data(historical data) and it failed

**Your new computed column is not unique**

Answer (score 0):

You can index [int] column instead of varchar(36), and save space more than twice.
Here is example demonstrating this:

```
use [tempdb];

if object_id('tempdb..#t1') is not null drop table [#t1];
if object_id('tempdb..#t2') is not null drop table [#t2];

-- create tables
create table [#t1] ([guid] varchar(36), [guid_int] int);
create table [#t2] ([guid] varchar(36), [guid_int] int);
-- dummy data
;with data as (select top  10000 [guid] = newid() from sys.columns t1 cross apply sys.columns t2) insert into [#t1] select [guid], convert(int, convert(binary, [guid])) from [data];
;with data as (select top  10000 [guid] = newid() from sys.columns t1 cross apply sys.columns t2) insert into [#t2] select [guid], convert(int, convert(binary, [guid])) from [data];
-- create indexes
create nonclustered index [ix_#t1_guid]     on [#t1]([guid]);
create nonclustered index [ix_#t2_guid_int] on [#t2]([guid_int]);
-- check space used
exec sp_spaceused N'tempdb..#t1';
exec sp_spaceused N'tempdb..#t2';
```

**Using int column instead of varchar(2) you have:**
a) more uniqueness b) int index size is smaller than varchar(2)

Comment: You don't have uniqueness. Guids are 128 bit integers. Casting them as binary then `int` will preserve 32 bits from one end and truncate the rest. Also the size consumed by `int` and the size of `varchar(2)` is the same - both 4 bytes (and `char(2)` 2 bytes). This will be a better use of that 4 bytes though as the `varchar(2)` will only have 256 distinct possibilities where this *may* use the whole range of `int` and so be more selective. Applying a good hash would be a better way of achieving this result though rather than relying on the GUID generation giving a good distribution.

Comment: Youre right, no uniqueness here. But, it is far more unique, than use left 2 symbols.